# Creating View Model and receiving uncaught type error, cannot read property map of undefined

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, viewmodel

I have a JS view model file, where I am creating an observable array to keep track of checkboxes being selected in my view. When I run, I get:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

Here is the code for my view model. Is there something I am missing or doing wrong?

```
var ProcessorReviewerSubLoanTypesViewModel = function (obj, token) {
obj = obj || {
    //For Reviewer SubLoanTypes
    PrsnPk: 0,
    AppInstId: 0,
    SubLoanTypes: []
};

var self = this;

var isUnchecked = ko.observableArray();

//set up anti-forgery tokens for ajax calls to server
$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: { 'RequestVerificationToken': token }
});

self.PrsnPk = ko.observable(obj.PrsnPk);
self.AppInstId = ko.observable(obj.AppInstId);

//Observable array to keep track of Reviewer SubLoanTypes that are selected in view
self.SubLoanTypes = ko.observableArray(obj.SubLoanTypes.map(function (element) {
    if (element.IsActivated === false) {
        isUnchecked.push(element.IsActivated);
    }
    return {
        VaFHATypeID: ko.observable(element.VaFHATypeID),
        IsActivated: ko.observable(element.IsActivated)
    };
}));
```

Comment: What do you get if you `console.log(obj)` before the `.map` function?

Comment: Let me see @AnuragSrivastava

Comment: This page is paginated with multiple panels, so I don't think logging obj will work, since there are other "obj"s in other view models. Nothing came up. @AnuragSrivastava

Comment: The error definitely states that `obj.SubLoanTypes` is `undefined`, so that is where I would look.

Answer (score 0):

Upon pondering at my code, I realized I had a typo in my ajax call to my controller function... (:

This has resolved the issue.